# VB: How to set up daily/weekly/periodic XML check

Tags: asp.net, xml, vb.net, visual-studio-2008

I'm currently pulling XML data from a third party source and displaying all the elements on a single web page. What I'm trying to do is dynamically create individual web pages for each element, and I'm not exactly sure what the best approach is.

My thought is that I need to run a daily query on the XML, store the new elements in a db, and create new web pages for the new elements.

So my question is - how (and where) do I run this daily query? Is that even the most efficient way of doing this?

I'm using Visual Studio 2008 and the asp.NET web forms framework with VB.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

This is a duplicate of this question (which was closed):
[What kinds of job scheduler framework or solution do you recomend on window server system](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2628983/what-kinds-of-job-scheduler-framework-or-solution-do-you-recomend-on-window-serv)

Without getting into the debate, I think you have two choices, Windows Scheduler or SQL Agent. Both are powerful and easy to use. Generally, I would standardize on SQL Agent, because most scheduled jobs involve data and I just hate having things in two different places. One of them always gets forgotten.